# Proper way to hash a reader in Rust?

Tags: hash, rust

I was attempting to use [twox-hash](https://crates.io/crates/twox-hash) to generate a hash for a file, as it seemed to be the fastest hash implementation around  and security is not a concern for this implementation.

To get it to work with a reader, I implemented a wrapper struct that implemented the `Write` trait and directly called `XxHash::write` from the `Hash` trait. Is there a more elegant or standard way of doing this?

```
#[derive(Deref)]
struct HashWriter<T: Hasher>(T);

impl<T: Hasher> std::io::Write for HashWriter<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.0.write(buf);
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, it lets you use [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/fn.copy.html)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what I would do, although I'd also implement `write_all` as it can be equally as simple:

```rust
use std::{hash::Hasher, io};

struct HashWriter<T: Hasher>(T);

impl<T: Hasher> io::Write for HashWriter<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        self.0.write(buf);
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.write(buf).map(|_| ())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

You can then use it like:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use twox_hash::XxHash64;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open file");

    let hasher = XxHash64::with_seed(0);
    let mut hw = HashWriter(hasher);

    io::copy(&mut f, &mut hw).expect("Unable to copy data");

    let hasher = hw.0;
    println!("{}", hasher.finish());
}
```

---

Disclaimer: I am the author / porter of twox-hash.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't implement `Write` directly?

Comment: Good point about write_all. Is there a particular reason that this isn't integrated into the std hash library so you can use a reader/writer with any hash?

Comment: @Stefan just because it doesn't really feel like the "right" thing to do for a hasher.

Comment: @spease If you cannot find an existing one, I'd say you should publish your shim to crates.io. It can wrap any type that implements `Hasher` and be generally useful. I don't know the reason, but having easily accessible crates lowers the rationale to have it in the standard library.